# documenting div sections, use title attribute?

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm looking for the most terse way to document sections of my page, e.g. div sections.

Anything wrong with using the title attribute, e.g.

```
<div title="Payment Area" class="form">
   ...
</div>
```

?

P.S.  In case relevant, I'm using the IntelliJ IDE, but new to its various capabilities, e.g. automatic formatting control and other ways to be able to easily understand sections of my pages.

Comment: If an element has a `title` attribute, most browsers show a tooltip with the attribute’s value when you hover over it. In this case, they’ll show a “Payment Area” tooltip when you hover *anywhere* over that `div`. So, it might not be appropriate.

Comment: Cool, thanks Sidnicious.  I forgot that.  You're right, wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Years late here, but if it's a comment, use a comment. Also, any worthwhile web framework allows for composing views from partials, so make a high level skeleton and name your partials well and more than half of the problem you're having here will solve itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use `id`s, that way you can also use them as hooks for your CSS and JavaScript.

Otherwise, [Gabe's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439266/14363557) makes a good case for `data` attributes.  John Resig explains why they are good here: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: I don't think I want to imply I'm using this information for anything, other than documenting what a section is for.   If I am applying a style or using javascript, then I would use a more condensed description, without spaces, etc.  Some of my descriptions are longer.

Comment: Sure @Ray.  But why not combine the two... save space and time?

Comment: Let's say I have 4 divs (sections) that use the same class styling, and other than that do nothing special.  To me if I use the id attribute, with a more variable like name, I'm implying functionality / complexity.  I don't want to do that.  I'd use a comment to document, but this way seems more succinct to me.

Comment: Ok.  But if you give them an `id` with a functional name, like `id="payment_area"`, then 1. you have documented the `div` and 2. made your code future friendly in case you want to add functionality or specific styles.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this then makes me wonder if there is a style for payment_area somewhere, or perhaps it's being used by javascript.  I'm an css/html "newbie", but doesn't sectioning things like this also imply additional complexity?  Perhaps I could use one or the other depending on whether there really is additional "id-specific" functionality for this div?

Comment: The problem with using `@title` is that it is exposed to users through hover and through announcement in assistive technology (ie: screenreaders). You shouldn't pollute the user space with your development documentation.

Comment: No additional complexity @Ray, as you are cutting down on the code you are writing.  I get how one could think there might be a style/script for the `id`... but you know your own code ;-)  Others would figure it out pretty quick by searching your CSS and JS files.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this might be the best solution, since I can't seem to use other non-html-5 attributes.  Perhaps I'll use a leading "c_" to indicate this is just a comment, and is not used for any styling or javascript. ... I'm afraid using the data- attributes will force me to switch my pages to html5 ... and not sure what impact that has.  Perhaps I need to search / ask a question on it.  Do you know about html5 adoption in older browsers / versions?

Comment: Do you by chance know about html 5 adoption in various browsers / versions.  Going to html 5 for something like this might not be worth it?

Answer (score 17):

If an element has a `title` attribute, most browsers show a tooltip with the attribute’s value when you hover over it. In this case, they’ll show a “Payment Area” tooltip when you hover *anywhere* over that `div`.

HTML attributes, in general, have a purpose. HTML has comments for documentation! Try them:

```
<div class="form"> <!-- Payment Area -->
    ...
</div>
```

You mentioned that you didn't want the overhead of comments. If you count up the characters (including the required space before the attribute, they're actually the same length:

```
 title="Payment Area"
<!-- Payment Area -->
```

(But, I agree, they do look bigger!)

Comment: :-)   Yah, I wanted to avoid the extra line and find something that describes the div (section) itself -- on same line.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with using the id, giving it a special naming convention if this element has no special style or javascript associated with it, e.g. id="c__Payment_Area".   Then, if it has javascript or css associated with it, I'll change it to id="paymentArea". ... perhaps I should do id="c__paymentArea"

Comment: @Ray I agree that comments do feel a little bigger than attributes, but they work just as well on the same line (see edit). If you would rather use an attribute, why not give each element a normal `id` (like `paymentArea`), regardless of whether that `id` is used by CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks Sidnicious, I guess with the id they are a little smaller.  I think one hold back I've had is using various editor formatters and having them move stuff around in ways I don't like.  But outside that, I think Jason's answer and associated comments are good.

Comment: Alternate idea: Use PHP comments instead of HTML comments - if it has no bearing on how the web page will be affected, users don't need to see it in the source.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the HTML5 custom attributes standard:

```
<div data-title='Payment Area'></div>
```

Basically, precede the name with `data-` and the browser will ignore it.

Comment: Ok .. that's less terse though.  Is there an advantage?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use the id attribute, then it's just the standard I follow, since HTML5 is showing up more and more. Just trying to follow recommended practices.

Comment: Gabe, if I used something like "data-c", c is for comment, how will older browsers treat this?

Comment: Pretty sure it would just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The title attribute isn't meant for divs - I haven't checked the official specs, but I don't think it's even a supported attribute. The better practice is to use the "id" attribute. This has the added benefit of providing hooks for your CSS.

You can also take it a step further and use html5, which provides you with more descriptive elements such as `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<article>` and `<header>`

---

Edit: as per comment by steveax, the title attribute isn't invalid. I think the gist of my answer remains valid, though.

Comment: I don't think I want to imply I'm using this information for anything, other than documenting what a section is for.  Do you know how the aforementioned html5 elements degrade in browsers (or browser versions) not yet supporting html5?

Comment: I personally find the ID useful for my own organization - the css is an added benefit. As for html5, you can make IE handle them easily - in the <head> of your page, using conditional comments, simply use javascript to create the appropriate element - you don't even need to insert it into the DOM. Then you can style it as if it were a <div>, or anything.

Comment: Follow up on last comment: example: `document.createElement('article');` Now IE won't freak out.

Comment: [Title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-title-attribute) is fine on a `div`, but it's for users _not_ authors. Misusing `@title` for author documentation is a bad practice. Why not just use comments?

Comment: Thanks steveax.  Yah, I don't want the user to see tooltips.  I wanted something more succinct than comments -- e.g. not a separate line, not extra < >.   It looks like perhaps my solution is to use something like <div data-c="Bla bla bla">, as long as older non-html5 browsers don't get bothered, which I don't know ??

Answer (score -1):

You can use the rel="" attribute, that works pretty well for me, I don't think title works on divs

```
<div rel="Payment Area"></div>
```

Comment: hmm, thanks.  Any "collision" with other uses of this attribute?  Wait a minute, isn't this attribute just for links?

Comment: No, please do not invent `@rel` types. That is not a valid use of [`@rel`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/links.html)

Comment: @steveax - you probably didn't see this comment, semi-hidden in the previous answer:  Yah, I don't want the user to see tooltips. I wanted something more succinct than comments -- e.g. not a separate line, not extra < >. It looks like perhaps my solution is to use something like <div data-c="Bla bla bla">, as long as older non-html5 browsers don't get bothered, which I don't know ??

Comment: Why don't you try it, I have used it before and it worked perfectly in my situation, I was able to refer to it using JQuery, don't listen to steveax :)

Comment: @steveax unless you have something useful to add to the answer, go -ve some other people

Comment: @Reina I think steveax is totally right, because you are using an attribute which are not supposed to be used like this, so the code becomes semantically incorrect. Be aware that if something works doesn't mean it's good. And you shouldn't get angry when someones criticizes your answer constructively.